In KDE, icons/visual display enlarged after update to Noble Numbat (Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS)
After updating my server (which runs KDE) from Jammy Jellyfish to Noble Numbat (Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS), the visual display of all the icons is very much enlarged, as though scale has been set to 150%.
Similar posts about this issue appearing within KDE on ArchLinux are here, here, and here. However, I can't follow the recommended fix (updating the /etc/sddm.conf file to include [X11] [new line] ServerArguments=-nolisten tcp -dpi 96) because there's no sddm.conf file in /etc.
There is a /sddm folder, which contains a file Xsession--but I'm not sure if this needs to be updated instead. There's also a /sddm.conf.d folder which contains 2 files (default.conf and kubuntu_settings.conf)--but including the above text ([X11] ServerArguments=-nolisten tcp -dpi 96) to these files and rebooting did not address this issue.
Finally, there's also an /etc/X11 folder with many files/folders (including something called Xsession.options). But I'm out of my depth and don't know what needs to change here to fix the issue. Thanks very much for any recommendations!
(Context: I administer this server remotely and ssh in, so I actually haven't witnessed this display behavior myself. I'm limited by how frequently there's a user onsite who can let me know whether or not any fix I've implemented has worked. I've also posted this question on Kubuntu forums).

I have the same isssue with clean install ubuntu 24.04 on my laptop.
Open KDE "System settings" dialog and go to Appearance-->Global Theme-->Fonts-->Force font DPI 96 (Enable checkbox)
